# Hibernate ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = bytea No operator matches the given name and argument types might need to add explicit type casts

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

While executing the following native query I am getting the above mentioned error.
I am using hibernate with postgresql database.

```
String query = "SELECT  requester_id,operator_id,date(qr_gen_date_time) as date, sum(ticket_fare) as total_amount, count(*) as ticket_count "
+ "FROM ticket_info tktInfo INNER JOIN operator_info op on tktInfo.operator_info_id = op.id" + "INNER JOIN ticket tkt on op.ticket_id =  tkt.id "
+ "WHERE (requester_id = :requesterId or :requesterId isNull) "
+ " AND (operator_id = :operatorId or :operatorId isNull) "
+ " AND (date(qr_gen_date_time) >= :dateFrom or :dateFrom isNull) "
+ " AND (date(qr_gen_date_time) <= :dateTo or :dateTo isNull) "
+ "GROUP BY date(qr_gen_date_time),requester_id,operator_id "
+ "ORDER BY date(qr_gen_date_time) DESC "
+ "LIMIT 10 OFFSET ( :pageNum -1 ) * 10 ";

List<Tuple> result= entityManager.createNativeQuery(query, Tuple.class)
                                .setParameter("requesterId", requesterId)
                                .setParameter("operatorId", operatorId)
                                .setParameter("dateFrom", dateFrom)
                                .setParameter("dateTo", dateTo)
                                .setParameter("pageNum", pageNum).getResultList();
```

Exception :

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = bytea
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 282
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing null for a parameter, Hibernate usually relies on inference in HQL to determine the type of the parameter. Since this is a native query though, Hibernate does not know the type of the parameter and in 5.6 by default chooses to bind such nulls with `PreparedStatement#setBytes`. The JDBC driver then assumes that this is of the type `bytea` and a predicate like `operator_id = ?` will compare an `integer` against a `bytea` in case you bind null.

In your particular case, the only way you can make this work is by specifying the type during parameter binding. You can do that through the `org.hibernate.query.Query` API which allows you to specify an optional third argument in `setParameter`/`setParameterList`, which represents the type of the value. Use `StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER` as argument and the query should work as intended.